# How to execute an insert or update operation in postgres 10 ( that not have store procedures)?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgres-10

it is possible to execute an insert or update operation using only functions in postgres?.
I am using version 10.14 that not support store procedures.

Comment: Yes you can. In lower version (9.5, 9.6, 10.0) of postgresql function behaves like stored procedure.

Comment: @RahulBiswas, functions where not/are not stored procedures that is why stored procedures where added. Two big differences 1) Stored procedures can contain transactions, functions do not. 2) Functions can have a `return` value store procedures do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`. It doesn't matter much if you run that from a function or not.